# Why does wordpress keep adding postname to my CPT's permalink in the end?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

Alternate Question: How to change Permalink structure for CPT so that post name comes in the middle of URL instead of in the end eg. `/a/%postname%/b/c`

Any suggestions while changing the permalink structure in custom post type? Right now I want the struct to be `/a/%postname%/b/c` but it keeps adding postname in the end by default like `/a/%postname%/b/c/%postname%` .

Here's my `register_post_type` code,

```
$args = array(
    'label' => __('testCPT', 'text_domain'),
    'description' => __('Site articles.', 'text_domain'),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'supports' => array('title', 'revisions'),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => '/a/%postname%/b/c',
        'with_front'    => false
    ),
);
```

Structure generated:

> http://localhost/project/a/yoda/b/c/yoda/

Structure Desired:

> http://localhost/project/a/yoda/b/c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should use `%<post type>%` in the `slug` value, so if the post type is `test_cpt`, then you would use `%test_cpt%` as in `/a/%test_cpt%/b/c`.

And moving the post name/slug to the middle or beginning in the permalink structure is actually pretty easy:

1. Register the post type:

   ```php
   // replace test_cpt with the correct post type
   register_post_type( 'test_cpt', $args );
   ```
2. Then after that, do this:

   ```php
   global $wp_rewrite;
   // replace test_cpt with the correct post type
   $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['test_cpt']['struct'] = '/a/%test_cpt%/b/c';
   ```

And *remember to flush the rewrite rules* which can be done just by visiting the permalink settings page.